# Save favorites to prevent updates delete them

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As the title says, I'm searching for a way to store favorites somewhere in order to prevent, when I release an update, to delete them.

My app is mainly made of a tableView handled by a plist which contains the sections,rows, id of the item and also the bool to check if the specific element is a favorite or not. Favorites elements are stored in another tableView (but it's always the same plist).

What I want to do is to save all favorites the user stored in somewhere  (maybe in another plist?) so that when the app receives an update, the user doesn't lose the items they stored (I guess that's because the update overwrites the already existing plist with default values - all items favorites = NO) and they can have them right inside it without having to re-favorite all items again.

Is there a way to do it?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at NSUserDefaults. This is the standard mechanism for persisting user preferences, which is essentially what favourites are. NSUserDefaults persist between app upgrades as long as the user doesn't delete the app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Already thought about it, the point is that I don't know how to organize the correspondence between ID and favorite bool keys. I mean, i should loop into plist, check if user has some favorite bool set to ON and store them or what?

Comment: I don't quite understand how you are managing your favourites today, you mention storing them in a second tableView, but a tableView obviously doesn't store data, just presents it. If you want to retrieve a single list of objects that have been favourited with the default method you could store the list as an array in the the defaults store, updating the array and re-persisting each time they change, although I would perhaps suggest you want to think about having a property on your data object behind each row and persisting individual index IDs as to whether or not a given object is favourited

Comment: Practically I have the first tableView which shows all plist data. Another tableView shows ONLY favorites (so, isFavorite key in plist set to YES)

Comment: Sorry, was still updating my comment (pressed enter by mistake) see the update above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see what I can do with that.